# Why does dev tool lists this inline element as block?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

What is this sorcery? inline overrules all other rules but it says it is block.

The code is below (the problem is with the div, not the nested span):

```css
  .mycaption {
  position: absolute; 
  left:5%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  display: inline;
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mycaption">
  <span>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed DO eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim AD minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip EX ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span>
</div>
```

[**JSBin.**](https://jsbin.com/vezomacuwe/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Can you make a snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: added one @mrlister. BoltClock, what do you mean by float? I assigned no floats.

Comment: Apparently, the `position:absolute` causes the browser to overrule the `display:inline` and use the default `block`. Which is odd, because a quick test shows that it doesn't overrule `display:none`. I need some more testing and browsing of w3.org before I can come up with an answer.

Comment: @Mr Lister: This is where the concepts of specified and computed values come into play. The specified value does not change; the computed value does. And the computed value is different based on what the original specified value was - in the case of `display: none` for example, it makes no sense to force an element to generate a box just by specifying it should be absolutely positioned, if you've already specified that *it should not generate a box in the first place*. The section of the spec that you'll want to look at is https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: @BoltClock Yes; Garbee already posted that link in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because an absolutely positioned element is taken *[out of the content flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#abs-pos)*, therefore it [can't be "inline"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#dis-pos-flo) with anything. It can be `flex`, `block`, `none`, or any other display types that aren't related to the existing content flow.